# My data from <script> returns None: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I try to get the data from within the <script> tag but 'model_data' return None.
When I run the code I get the error:
model_data = model_data.group(1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

What is wrong here?

```
html_doc = """
    <script>
      var modelData = {
        "hlsUrl": "null",
        "account": "4LH7J44IYPAGEZEY6E3UL"
      }
  </script>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")
# locate the script, get the contents
script_text = soup.select_one("script").contents[0]

# get javascript object inside the script
model_data = re.search(r"modelData = ({.*?});", script_text, flags=re.S)
print(model_data) # RETURNS None - why?
model_data = model_data.group(1)

# "convert" the javascript object to json-valid object
model_data = re.sub(
    r"^\s*([^:\s]+):", r'"\1":', model_data.replace("'", '"'), flags=re.M
)

# json decode the object
model_data = json.loads(model_data)

# print the data
print(model_data["account"])
```

**Updated issue:**

After accepted the answer which worked with the given response, I found out that I had left out an important piece of information.

The full response is like this:

```
{
        "hlsUrl": "null",
        "account": "1V2FO4K7ME78RV09VXNEC",
        "packageName": "null",
        isActive: false
      }
```

Here it shows that isActive is not a json like object or what it's called, so it gives me now the following error:

```
obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 5 column 9 (char 111)
```

Comment: `group(0)`? it is 0-indexed based

Comment: ah ok thanks for that :) , but it still doesn't change that 'model_data' return None.

Comment: because the regex pattern is not correct

Comment: Can you elaborate on that and maybe help me make it right then?

Comment: You sure the response comes *without* the quotes? If there's no quotes that's not a valid JSON.

Comment: @baduker yes, isActive: false comes without the qoutes. It is not valid JSON. That's why I in my originally posted code as seen, has made the # "convert" the javascript object to json-valid object. But something is wrong with the regex. I have so many problems with regex, it's simply to complicated for me for now.

Comment: Do you need this `is Active` key? And where do you get that response from? Is this from an API, AJAX, a JavaScript var?

Comment: @baduker No, I don't need the isActive key at all. I only need hlsUrl. And I scrape a website where there are some JavaScript's and then there's just this in a <script> tag without any other info assigned to it.

Comment: If you don't need it and that's the only key with quotes, then just remove it and parse the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making it a bit too complicated than it really has to be.

Use `.string` not `.contents[0]`. As the later works too, the `.string` method doesn't need indexing and can be directly passed to `re.search()`. Also, IMHO, it's more readable.

Fix your regex.

This works:

```
modelData = ({.*?})
```

while this does not:

```
modelData = ({.*?});
```

Notice, there's no need for `;`

Finally, you don't have to do all this:

```
# "convert" the javascript object to json-valid object
model_data = re.sub(
    r"^\s*([^:\s]+):", r'"\1":', model_data.replace("'", '"'), flags=re.M
)
```

Just simply dump the regex `group(1)` to `json.loads`.

Full code:

```
import json
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
    <script>
      var modelData = {
        "hlsUrl": "null",
        "account": "4LH7J44IYPAGEZEY6E3UL"
      }
  </script>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")
script_text = soup.select_one("script").string
model_data = re.search(r"modelData = ({.*?})", script_text, re.S).group(1)
print(json.loads(model_data)["account"])
```

Output:

```
4LH7J44IYPAGEZEY6E3UL
```

Comment: Can you take a look at my update in the original question please?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a case where you can *search* the HTML content for exactly what you're looking for instead of doing any intermediate parsing

```py
html_doc = """
    <script>
      var modelData = {
        "hlsUrl": "null",
        "account": "4LH7J44IYPAGEZEY6E3UL"
      }
  </script>
"""
```

```py
import re
next(re.finditer(r'"account":\s*"([\dA-Z]{21})"', html_doc)).group(1)
# '4LH7J44IYPAGEZEY6E3UL'
```

This works by finding the first instance of literally `"account":` followed by any amount of whitespace `\s*` and then a quoted string with exactly 21 uppercase digits or letters (tune `21` to the possible range)

`re.finditer()` and `next()` are helpful here because they'll

- search the entire string until a match is found
- get only the first instance or raise `StopIteration`
- be surprisingly fast

While this avoids any intermediate parsing and doesn't attempt to parse the html with regex (which [can only lead to ZA̡͊͠͝LGΌ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4541045)), beware it can break if a similar field appears in unrelated scopes! If you expect such a case, adapting [**@baduker**'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67064890/4541045) will likely be more robust. Conversely, if you expect the structure to change, but *not* find an exactly-matching field (`"account":\s*"([\dA-Z]{21})"`), this may be more robust (as it doesn't care about the other HTML structure such as finding the `<script>`)